# HyperPay Integration With Magetno 2

Tags: payment-gateway, magento2

Dears, Any body has an experience with HypePay Payment Method?

I need to integrate HyperPay with Magento 2. Is there is any extension or Custom Code?

Comment: did you get any result on this ?